# rails4 debugging breakpoints with ruby 1.9.3?

Tags: ruby, debugging, ruby-on-rails-4

What do people use to set debugging breakpoints in Rails4 with Ruby 1.9.3?  I used to use rdebug but that doesn't work with Rails4 and ruby 1.9.3.

I've tried

```
ruby-debug     - doesn't install with ruby 1.9.3
byebug         - needs ruby 2.0
ruby-debug-ide - get error = cannot load such file -- ruby-debug-base (LoadError)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [debugger](https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger). In general, do this

```
ruby-debug - for ruby 1.8
debugger   - for ruby 1.9
byebug     - for ruby 2.0
```

and things should be fine.

Comment: So nice!  Thank ya kindly!